# bind two arrays to each other using knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have one ViewModel that contains two arrays: `arr1` and `arr2`. I would like `arr2` to contains exactly what the `arr1` contains. How can I do that?

```
var myViewModel = function() {
    this.arr1 = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.arr2 = ko.observableArray(this.arr1); //Doesn't work - I need to bind arr2 to changes in arr1
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to store reference to array's elements use should unwrap observable:

```
var myViewModel = function() {
    this.arr1 = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.arr2 = ko.observableArray(this.arr1());
}
```

If want clone array use `Slice` function of array:

```
var myViewModel = function() {
    this.arr1 = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.arr2 = ko.observableArray(this.arr1.slice(0)); 
}
```

Comment: Is there a way such that both arrays will update each other like change in arr1 will set arr2 and change in arr2 will set arr1 (It doesn't have to change the arrays, both arrays can manipulate one array)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want copy first array to second **once** you can crate copy of arrya, using function `ko.toJS` or `ko.toJSON`

```
var myViewModel = function() {
    this.arr1 = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.arr2 = ko.observableArray(ko.toJS(this.arr1)); 
}
```

if you want change second array each time, when first is changed use subscriber

```
var myViewModel = function() {
    this.arr1 = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.arr2 = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.arr2.subscribe(function(newValue) {
       this.arr2(ko.toJS(this.arr1));
    });
}
```

Comment: I like to store reference to array's elements. @Artem Vyshniakov helps me. Thanks!